# JavaScript - Submit Form with localtime

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, time

I'm trying to combine Submit form and date/localtime

submit from every time "15:30:00"

here goes my code js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initClock() 
{
  var now = new Date();
  var hr  = now.getHours();
  var min = now.getMinutes();
  var sec = now.getSeconds();
  if (min < 10) min = "0" + min; 
  if (sec < 10) sec = "0" + sec;
  var time = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
      time.innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  setTimeout('initClock()', 500);
}

function timesubmit()
{
    if (time.innerHTML == "15:30:00") // time submit 15:30:00
        {
          document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        } 
    else 
        {
          //etc
        }
}
</script>
```

and my HTML code goes like this:

```
<body onload="initClock()">
<div id="clockDisplay"></div>
<br>
<form id="myForm" action="http://example.com" method="post">
<input type="submit" onclick="timesubmit()" value="send"  />
</form>
</body>
```

Any idea how I can get it to work? if time "15:30:00" auto submit form

Thanks for everybody who can help me :D

Comment: what problems are you facing specifically? any errors?

Comment: Simply pasting code here, its better you paste on fiddle and give us a link

Comment: not work to me, this http://jsfiddle.net/wbSbF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqCQ6/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="clockDisplay"></div>
<br>
<form id="myForm" action="http://example.com" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="timesubmit()" value="send"  />
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",initClock,false);
var timeStamp;
function initClock() 
{
  var now = new Date();
  var hr  = now.getHours();
  var min = now.getMinutes();
  var sec = now.getSeconds();
  if (hr < 10) hr = "0" + hr; 
  if (min < 10) min = "0" + min; 
  if (sec < 10) sec = "0" + sec;
  timeStamp= hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  var time = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
  time.innerHTML = timeStamp;
  timesubmit();
  setTimeout(initClock, 0);
}

function timesubmit()
{
    if (timeStamp == "15:30:00") // time submit 15:30:00
        {
          document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        } 
    else 
        {
          //etc
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wbSbF/1/

The changes are:

```
//so timesubmit can return false to stop the submit action, return true to continue.
onclick="return timesubmit()"

//'initClock()' seemed works fine too, but I prefer just initClock
//setTimeout(initClock, 500);

//define time in timesubmit function
var time = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
```